# como puedo hacer en C que me muestre el menu si no se da ningun case, lo que hace es salirse

Tags: c

[image: codigo]

como puedo hacer en C que me muestre el menu si no se da ningun case, lo que hace es mostrar la letra hasta que desaparece el menu, me gustaria que se mostrase el printf y que vuelva a salir el menu en bucle hasta poner una opcion del case.

Comment: por favor mira [ask]. Asi como esta, no se entiende nada de tu problema. Se claro explicando el mismo.

Comment: Lo siento pero no se entiende tu pregunta ni to código.

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: y de paso mostra como esta definida la variable opcion

Comment: perdona intentare ponerlo nuevamente pero tampoco me dejaba copiar y pegar directamente.

Comment: No puedo ver el código de tus imágenes. De todas maneras esta es una página sobre código, no sobre capturas de pantalla ¿Por qué poner capturas en lugar de código? ¡es más complicado! y no se puede copiapegar el código de una imagen ni hacer búsquedas de texto; por favor: **PON EL CÓDIGO**, **NO IMÁGENES**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Sirio lo que debes hacer es poner el menu dentro de tu ciclo while y después del menu una entrada por teclado seguido del switch case que se ajuste a tu menu:

```
char respuesta = "";
bool bucle = true;
while (bucle) { //Inicia el bucle
     printf("Este es mi menu");
     printf("E. Editar ruta");
     printf("P. Programar calendario");
     printf("L. Listar datos de ruta y calendario");
     printf("C. Calendario mensual de trayecto");
     printf("I. Información de viaje");
     printf("S. Salir");
     scanf(" %c", &respuesta)

     switch (respuesta) { //Aqui inicia el menu 
         case: "E"
             //Pon tu código aqui
             break;
         case: "P"
             //Pon tu código aqui
             break;
         case: "L"
             //Pon tu código aqui
             break;
         case: "C"
             //Pon tu código aqui
             break;
         case: "I"
             //Pon tu código aqui
             break;
         case: "S"
             bucle = false; //Termina el bucle para salir del menu;
             break;
         default: printf("Opción invalida inténtelo de nuevo");
     } //Cierra el menu
} //Cierra el ciclo
```

En todo caso si quisieras salir del bucle luego de cualquiera de las opciones del menú lo único que debes hacer es cambiar el valor de la variable bucle `bucle = false` y de esa forma terminas el bucle en cualquier momento.

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que buscaba.

Comment: @Siro, si esta respuesta ha resuelto tu problema, por favor marca la respuesta como válida.

Comment: @Siro, te agradecería que marques la respuesta como valida si te ayudó!

Answer (score -2):

```
    while(1){
      if(opcion == 'E'){}
....
else
{
   printf(...);
}
    }
```

Prueba con condiciones if/else igual te es más fácil

Comment: Mas alla de que la respuesta es solo codigo (sin contexto), como arregla esto el problema (que honestamente no se cual es?)

Comment: El problema es que me gustaria que se mpostrase el printf del default al pulsar una tecla que no sea las que programe osea EPLCI con la S si que quiero que se salga del menu, pero si no es ninguna de esas teclas las que pone que repita el menu de inicio.